# Proplem while adding strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm not getting an error from javascript but the result I'm getting when the strings are added together is unexpected. This is my code and what I'm receiving

```
var result = "x"
addstr("1")

var addstr = function(str){
    var result = result + str
    alert(result)
}
```

I belive I should be getting the result of x1. Then next time I execute the function x11. and then x111 etc... but the result I'm getting is 'undefined1'. I've run it again and I'm getting the exact same error, 'undefined1'. I have no idea what is going on and I'm sure the awnser is simple, though I've looked for a while and haven't seen anyone having this 'problem' also, please take in account I'm very new to javascript. Thank you for your time.

Can i have some example code which would solve this proplem?

Comment: Because by putting `var` before `result` in your function you are creating a local scope variable `result` and it will not use the global scope `result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `var` in function with result makes it a local variable. So you have different(local) version of result in function not the original result that you wanted from outside.

Remove `var` keyword in function.Change it to

```
var result = "x"
addstr("1")

var addstr = function(str){
    result = result + str
    alert(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, As i said, i'm new to java script, and i hope i didnt waste your time on a question with an obvious awnser, thanks anyway :D

Comment: it happens.no problem it is pleasure helping others :)

Answer (score 0):

A `var` declaration creates a local variable. Your `result` inside the function shadows the `result` that is outside the function, and because you're using it before it's initialized, its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

addstr("1") is a string not an integer
also you forgot semicolon after result
so

```
 result="x"
becomes 
result ="x";
```

also remove var from your function

```
var addstr = function(str){
     result = result + str
    alert(result)
}
```